# setting parameters in postgresql.conf file(log file not getting truncated)

Tags: postgresql

In my `postgresql.conf` file, I have the following settings

```
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%a.log'
log_truncate_on_rotation = on
log_rotation_size = 10
```

But my log file is not getting truncated after 10 KB. please help.

Comment: Did you reload Postgres after you modified the configuration file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The log truncation doesn't happen because `postgres` has a protection to avoid truncating a log file that appears to be the same as the one it's currently logging into. Otherwise that would mean loosing the latest log entries, which seems hardly ever desirable.
In fact, the doc on `log_truncate_on_rotation` says:

> However, truncation will occur only when a new file is being opened
>   due to time-based rotation, not during server startup or size-based
>   rotation

To solve this, you should change `log_filename` from `'postgresql-%a.log'` to a name with a time granularity that is compatible with the `log_rotation_size`. As an example:

> log_filename = postgresql-%a-%H.log

With these settings, the purpose of `log_truncate_on_rotation` would be to overwrite the log of the previous day at the same hour for the same application name if it happens to exist.

I assume that you are just testing the log rotation feature, because in reality `10Kb` is too small to be useful, and overriding previous logs is dubious in production use. If you have hard constraints on the size of logs, you should combine the logfile switching done by postgres with an external cron job that aggressively removes the older logs as opposed to relying only on `log_truncate_on_rotation`.